# Facebook Request Dialog return bundle

Tags: android, facebook, apprequests

In [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) page I have seen that you can take two return data from a Request Dialog: "request" and "to" so i have done this

```
new Facebook.DialogListener() {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    Log.i("Bundle",values.toString());
    int[] nArray = values.getIntArray("to");
    int n = nArray.length;
}
```

But i Have a `NullPointerException` when i use the n variable. I am not sure that "to" is an intArray can someone tell me what is the type of nArray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Set<String> keys = values.keySet();
int n = keys.size() - 1;
```

Now n is the number of friends you have invited !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the debugger to step through this code?  You can set a breakpoint and try to call different methods in the Expressions tab of Eclipse to try and find out the right data type.

Also, what is the output of your Log message (`values.toString()`)?

Comment: This is the log message Bundle[{to[0]=1717519***, request=510342092******}] and i have tryed with everything. String, int, float, long..